# Axios request pending, but work on postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, nuxt.js

my Problem is:

I am creating an Nuxt application and i am testing the API endpoints.

For example when i using Postman and i send this request with POST:

```
localhost:3000/api/login
```

Everything is ok and i get the expected result back but when i try it on my client side with this:

```
 axios
      .post("/api/login", {
        email: email,
        password: passwort
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

On the network tab in google chrome i see that the request is pending and i dont know why.

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

  mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://mydata/realtime?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
  );


  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  const routes = require("./routes/routes");
  app.use(routes);
  module.exports = {
    path: "/api",
    handler: app
  };
```

This is my routes folder:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

import createUser from "../controllers/user";
import checkLogin from "../controllers/login";
/* GET users listing. */

router.post("/login", checkLogin);
router.post("/register", createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

and my `login.js` file:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
import User from "../models/user";
export default async function checkLogin(req, res) {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Diese E-Mail konnte nicht verifiziert werden."
    });
  }
  const checkPw = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (checkPw) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Erfolgreich eingeloggt"
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Falsche Passwort"
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I have founded the issue, i have forgot the `this` keyword in the data i pass:

```
 axios
  .post("/api/login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.passwort
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: have you tried using Async and await

Comment: The fact that your API never sent back a response when you sent it a bad user name and password apparently means you have error handling problems in your login API when bad data is sent to it and some path through it where you never send a response.  You need to fix that.  I see one problem now.  If `await User.findOne(...)` rejects, you have no `try/catch` that will handle that error.

Comment: i have fixed it, i forgot on my vue.js side to add `this` so i sended always an object instead of an string to the api